# "Install" option disappeared from the software center

Tags: apt, software-center

I cannot install anything from the Ubuntu software center (on 13.10). The "Install" button is missing and only the one fore "More information" is there. I suspect it is a problem with the software repository cause I have been messing up with it trying to install OpenOffice but I don't know how to fix it. Any help?

After introducing this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This is what resulted:

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for joan: 
Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease

Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                        
  No s'ha pogut resoldre «dl.google.com»
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                                       

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                                       

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                                     
  No es pot connectar amb ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                                     
  No es pot connectar amb extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://es.archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                                   

Err http://es.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates InRelease                           

Err http://es.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports InRelease                         

Err http://es.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                                 
  No es pot connectar amb es.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2a00:9ac0:c1ca:6::135 80]
Err http://es.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release.gpg     
  No es pot connectar amb es.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2a00:9ac0:c1ca:6::135 80]
Err http://es.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg   
  No es pot connectar amb es.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2a00:9ac0:c1ca:6::135 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security InRelease                 

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg          
  No es pot connectar amb security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
S'està llegint la llista de paquets… Fet
W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease  

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/InRelease  

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/InRelease  

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/InRelease  

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease  

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-1/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease  

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  No s'ha pogut resoldre «dl.google.com»

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-1/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release.gpg  No es pot connectar amb ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release.gpg  No es pot connectar amb extras.ubuntu.com:http:

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release.gpg  No es pot connectar amb es.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2a00:9ac0:c1ca:6::135 80]

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/Release.gpg  No es pot connectar amb es.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2a00:9ac0:c1ca:6::135 80]

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/Release.gpg  No es pot connectar amb es.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2a00:9ac0:c1ca:6::135 80]

W: No s'ha pogut obtenir http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/Release.gpg  No es pot connectar amb security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]

W: Alguns índex no s'han pogut baixar. S'han descartat, o en el seu lloc s'han emprat els antics.


jsudo apt-get dist-upgrade
S'està llegint la llista de paquets… Fet 
S'està construint l'arbre de dependències       
S'està llegint la informació de l'estat… Fet
S'està calculant l'actualització… Fet
0 actualitzats, 0 nous a instaŀlar, 0 a suprimir i 0 no actualitzats.
```

And this is the list of repositories:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
```

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: how do you copy the output from the terminal so that it appears nicely?

Comment: The es.archive.ubuntu.com mirror seems to be down or unstable. Select another mirrors in your software sources.

Comment: @Joan You either indent it by four spaces or select the code/output and click the `<$>` button in the edit toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` mirror seems to be unstable for the moment. You can select other mirrors using Software Sources or using this method from the command line:

```
sudo sed -i 's/es\.archive/archive/g' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Reopen the Software Center and you now should have the install button enabled.

Once you think that the mirror is backup, you can revert the changes using

```
sudo sed -i 's/archive/es.archive/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

and another way
- change your package server

```
search "Synaptic Package Manager" on "dash home"
and select following
 setting -> repositories -> ubuntu software
 select new server on "download from"
```

or see this link >> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The problem does not appear to be with **all** of the repositories (when looking at accepted answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to update your system first. You can do this in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, then please edit your answer, appending the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and the error messages resulting from the above commands. You can copy the contents of the file by running `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` in your terminal and then copying and pasting.

Comment: reason for downvote? It was by following my instructions that OP provided sufficient information for the accepted answer to be possible.